# Clean up very big and very dirty database

Tags: sql, customization

I'm trying to clean up a database in order to move a website from a server to another.
Database is more than 1gb, mostly posts revisions and spam comments.

Is it safe for instance to do something like this?

```
DELETE FROM wp_2_posts WHERE post_name LIKE '%revision%'
```

Thanks.

Comment: On a side-note, you can limit the number of revisions WordPress stores by adding this to the `wp-config.php` file: `define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3 );` - [Read More in The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions#Revision_Options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe but always prefer a database backup before. You can also try the [Minimise WordPress DB](https://websitespeedexperts.com/how-to-minimise-your-wordpress-database/) queries to clean more.

Comment: Those are some nice queries! I already reduced DB size to ~250mb by removing revisions, I'll do this too. Thanks!

Comment: wp-optimize is another good one https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/